Issue with Language Switching in Next.js 14 with i18next
I’m using Next.js 14 and i18next for language switching, but I’m encountering a problem when navigating between routes.
Framework and Libraries:
"next": "14.2.13",
"i18next": "^23.15.1",
"i18next-resources-to-backend": "^1.2.1",
"next-i18n-router": "^5.5.1",
"react-i18next": "^15.0.2"

The issue is that when I navigate to routes like:
/dashboard/path1
/dashboard/path2

with the language set to en, then go to /dashboard/path3 and change the language to another one, the pages that haven't been rendered yet display in the new language correctly. However, when I return to the previously visited routes (/dashboard/path1, /dashboard/path2), the language reverts back to en instead of showing the newly selected language.
Code snippets:
Here’s the setup for i18n-config.ts:
import { Config } from 'next-i18n-router/dist/types';

const i18nConfig: Config = {
  locales: [ 'en', 'fa' ],
  defaultLocale: 'fa'
} as const;

export type TLocale = (typeof i18nConfig)['locales'][number];

export default i18nConfig;


i18n.ts:
import { createInstance, i18n, Resource } from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next/initReactI18next';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import i18nConfig from '@/i18n-config';

export default async function initTranslations(
  locale: string,
  namespaces: string[],
  i18nInstance?: i18n,
  resources?: Resource
) {
  i18nInstance = i18nInstance || createInstance();
  
  i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next);
  
  if (!resources) {
    i18nInstance.use(
      resourcesToBackend(
        (language: string, namespace: string) =>
          import(`@/locales/${ language }/${ namespace }.json`)
      )
    );
  }
  
  await i18nInstance.init({
    lng: locale,
    resources,
    fallbackLng: i18nConfig.defaultLocale,
    supportedLngs: i18nConfig.locales,
    defaultNS: namespaces[ 0 ],
    fallbackNS: namespaces[ 0 ],
    ns: namespaces,
    preload: resources ? [] : i18nConfig.locales
  });
  
  return {
    i18n: i18nInstance,
    resources: i18nInstance.services.resourceStore.data,
    t: i18nInstance.t
  };
}

middleware.ts:
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
import { i18nRouter } from 'next-i18n-router';
import i18nConfig from './i18n-config';

export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(request) {
    return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ req, token }) => {
        return !((req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/dashboard') || req.nextUrl.pathname.includes(
          '/auth/create-app')) && token === null);
      }
    }
  }
);

export const config = {
  matcher: [ '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|.*\\..*|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)' ]
};

File structure:
src
  app
    [locale]
      layout.tsx
      page.tsx

layout.tsx:
export const generateStaticParams = async () => i18nConfig?.locales?.map(locale => ({ locale }));

const namespaces = [
  'common',
  'auth',
  'rulesMessage',
  'dashboard',
  'applications',
  'providers',
  'apis',
  'industries',
  'services',
  'reports',
  'requestMessages'
];

const RootLayout: FC<PropsWithChildren & TPropsWithLocaleParam> = async ({ children, params: { locale } }) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  
  const { resources, i18n: { dir } } = await initTranslations(locale, namespaces);
  
  return (
    <html lang={ locale } dir={ dir() }>
    <body className="!font-dynamicFont overflow-x-hidden">
    <AntdRegistry>
      <NextTopLoader />
      
      <TranslationsProvider locale={ locale } namespaces={ namespaces } resources={ resources }>
        <NextAuth session={ session }>
          { children }
        </NextAuth>
      </TranslationsProvider>
    </AntdRegistry>
    </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;

translations-provider.tsx:
'use client';

import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { createInstance, Resource } from 'i18next';
import initTranslations from '@/i18n';

export default function TranslationsProvider({
  children,
  locale,
  namespaces,
  resources
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  locale: string;
  namespaces: string[];
  resources: Resource;
}) {
  const i18n = createInstance();
  
  initTranslations(locale, namespaces, i18n, resources);
  
  return <I18nextProvider i18n={ i18n }>{ children }</I18nextProvider>;
}

language-switcher.tsx:
'use client';

import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import i18nConfig from '@/i18n-config';

export const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const currentLocale = i18n.language;
  const router = useRouter();
  const currentPathname = usePathname();
  
  const handleChangeLanguage = () => {
    const newLocale = currentLocale === 'en' ? 'fa' : 'en';
    
    // set cookie for next-i18n-router
    const days = 30;
    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const expires = date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = `NEXT_LOCALE=${ newLocale };expires=${ expires };path=/`;
    
    // Set the new locale in the i18n instance
    i18n.changeLanguage(newLocale);
    
    // Update the URL
    if (currentLocale === i18nConfig.defaultLocale && !i18nConfig.prefixDefault) {
      router.replace('/' + newLocale + currentPathname);
    }
    else {
      router.push(currentPathname.replace(`/${ currentLocale }`, `/${ newLocale }`));
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div
      className="--headerItems --rounded text-primary-0 text-captionMd capitalize cursor-pointer"
      onClick={ handleChangeLanguage }
    >
      { currentLocale === 'fa' ? 'en' : 'fa' }
    </div>
  );
};

Question:
Why is the language reverting back to en for previously visited routes (e.g., /dashboard/path1, /dashboard/path2) after switching languages? How can I ensure that when I switch languages, all routes consistently reflect the new language, regardless of whether they were previously rendered?
I tried using i18n.changeLanguage to update the language, and it works for routes that haven’t been rendered yet. I expected all routes, including previously visited ones, to update to the new language when I switch it. However, only the new routes show the updated language, while the old ones revert to the previously set language (en in this case).
